# Magento 1.9 return 403 error while uploading downloadable products

Tags: image-upload, downloadable, magento1.9.2.3, http-status-403

I am getting 403 error for downloadable products,

[image]

Comment: It seems to be file permission or htaccess issue

Comment: Which file I need to give write permission?

Comment: You need to give write permission to the destination folder where the files are stored and may on /var/tmp as well

Comment: After giving 777 permission to var/tmp still upload process return 403 error.

Comment: I just tried another option, image link https://snipboard.io/ENQFDk.jpg but after purchased products downloadable option not visible https://snipboard.io/k8e4j5.jpg

Comment: try this 
chmod -Rf 777 var
chmod -Rf 777 media